# Trump “can dish it out, but he can’t take it”?

Tags: phrase-meaning, ambiguity

In [this critical article on US sanctions](https://www.counterpunch.org/2020/04/08/amid-plague-sanctions-are-genocide/) I can't understand the meaning of the phrase quoted from the journalist.

> As one journalist noted, Trump – who sanctioned Russian firms but then phoned Putin about stabilizing oil prices – **“can dish it out, but he can’t take it.”** Iran, Venezuela and Cuba, however, have no such leverage.

I appreciate help with understanding the meaning here.

Comment: Hint: it's an idiom. (Have you looked it up?)

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Oh, one of those rare times you don't try google first and regret asking https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/someone-can-dish-it-out-but-he-or-she-can-t-take-it

Comment: @infatuated - you should _always_ research first before asking a question here.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Sure, but I just didn't even suspect this time that this might be an idiom, otherwise I routinely google or look up words and phrases I encounter in texts several times each day.

Comment: You thought the journalist invented it?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, sort of. I thought the meaning must be context-dependent.